# Do Macs Have Custom Models of Intel Processors?

Tags: macos, mac, processor

Do Apple Computers use the same-exact Intel processors available to PC builders or are they custom models made just for Apple? For example, if a Mac is marketed as having an Intel i7 3.3 GHz x-generation processor and there is a matching processor listed on [Ark](http://ark.intel.com/) for that chipset "generation," is it safe to assume that same-exact processor is in the Mac? Or does Apple get custom models within the chipset families just for their computers?

Also, is there a website where I can see the processor model numbers available in Macs so I don't have to spend time trying to match Apple's marketing to Intel's specs?

Answer (score 1):

They are identical. Don't know if we are allowed to talk about it, but all I can say is to search osx86project or tonymacx86, you will see the hardware.

List of [iMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_(Intel-based)) and [Macbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) hardware and history.

If you search the Intel chips the Macs are using (eg. i7-4770HQ), you will see Windows laptops are using them as well.

Mactracker is an [OSX App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mactracker/id430255202?mt=12) and an [iOS App](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/mactracker/id311421597?mt=8) that has all the details from the first Mac to the last Mac.

Comment: The original MacBook Air had a customized package for its CPU.  http://www.anandtech.com/show/2422 I think otherwise, they've been completely standard parts.